# KeyError on POST method in simple Flask python backend

Tags: python, api, server, postman, keyerror

I'm trying to create a simple API and server with MongoDB and Flask in python(pycharm). I'm testing the methods with Postman and so far the GET and DELETE methods work. I'm having troubles with the POST method mainly(for adding an entity). I have 2 classes

## repository class

```
class ExercisesRepository:

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        self.client.drop_database("exercise_database")  # clear everything that was before
        self.db = self.client.exercise_database  # create database
        self.exercises = self.db.exercises  # create table in the database

    def get_all(self):
        return [{
            'id': str(exercise['_id']),
            'type': exercise['type'],
            'calories': exercise['calories']
        } for exercise in self.exercises.find()]

    def add(self, exercise):
        exercise = {key: exercise[key] for key in exercise}
        exercise['calories'] = int(exercise['calories'])  #line 24
        self.exercises.insert_one(exercise)  # automatically generates an ObjectId for the exercise
        return 200

    def update(self, exercise_id, exercise):
        my_query = {"_id": ObjectId(exercise_id)}
        new_values = {"$set": {"type": exercise["type"], "calories": exercise["calories"]}}
        self.exercises.update_one(my_query, new_values)
        return 200

    def delete(self, exercise_id):
        self.exercises.remove(ObjectId(exercise_id))
        return 200

    def check_database_content(self):
        for exercise in self.exercises.find():
            pprint.pprint(exercise)
```

## server class

```
from ExercisesRepository import ExercisesRepository

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
import sys


app = Flask(__name__)

exerciseRepo = ExercisesRepository()

exerciseRepo.add({'type': 'Yoga', 'calories': 500})
exerciseRepo.add({'type': 'Walk', 'calories': 300})
exerciseRepo.add({'type': 'Run', 'calories': 100})


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


@app.route("/exercises", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def exercises():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return jsonify(exerciseRepo.get_all())
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form, file=sys.stderr)
        return jsonify(exerciseRepo.add(request.form))  #line 31


@app.route('/exercises/<exercise_id>', methods=['PUT', 'DELETE'])
def exercises_id(exercise_id):
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        print(request.form, file=sys.stderr)
        return jsonify(exerciseRepo.update(exercise_id, request.form))
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        return jsonify(exerciseRepo.delete(exercise_id))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I try to make a POST call in postman with a JSON like this : 
{
    "type": "Aerobic",
    "calories": 500
} I get the following message in postman: 500 Internal Server Error
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
and in Pycharm console:

> File "server.py", line 31, in exercises
>       return jsonify(exerciseRepo.add(request.form))
>       server\ExercisesRepository.py", line 24, in add
>       exercise['calories'] = int(exercise['calories']) 
>       KeyError: 'calories'
>   127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2020 13:01:50] "POST /exercises HTTP/1.1" 500 -

I'm pretty new to python and this is my first try to make an api so if you could explain as much as possible it would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: error shows that there is no `calories` in `exercise`  so better uses `print(exercise)` to see what you get in `exercise`. OR `print(request.form)` to see what you get from client.

Comment: if you send as `JSON` then you don't have it as `request.form` but `request.json`. `form` data are send like normal string `type=Aerobic&calories=500`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send data as `JSON` then you have to get it using `request.json`, not `request.form`

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/exercises", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def exercises():
    print('form:', request.form)
    print('json:', request.json)
    return jsonify(request.json)  #line 31

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When you send as `JSON`

```
import requests

r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/exercises', json={'type': 'Run', 'calories': 100})
```

then server shows

```
form: ImmutableMultiDict([])
json: {'type': 'Run', 'calories': 100}
```

When you send as `form` data

```
import requests

r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/exercises', data={'type': 'Run', 'calories': 100})
```

then server shows

```
form: ImmutableMultiDict([('type', 'Run'), ('calories', '100')])
json: None
```

---

`form` sends data as string `type=Run&calories=100` in body,
`json` sends data as string `{'type': 'Run', 'calories': 100}` in body.

You can see it if you display request's body

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data={'type': 'Run', 'calories': 100})
print(r.request.body)

r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', json={'type': 'Run', 'calories': 100})
print(r.request.body)
```

Result

```
type=Run&calories=100
b'{"type": "Run", "calories": 100}'
```